# Kendo UI Slider / how to disable keyboard input?

Tags: kendo-ui, slider

Is there a way to disable the keyboard events on Kendo UI Slider? Basically, I want to prevent changing the value of the slider when pressing left and right arrow keys. Is this possible at all?

Please note that slider is being dynamically inserted into the DOM as part of a KO custom binding handler.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.tone = {

  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

    if (valueAccessor().settingToneEnabled) {

      var $el = $(element);
      var tag = '<span class="dropdown mrgn-tp-md"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-tone id="tonedropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"></a><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-center pddng-sm" aria-labelledby="tonedropdownMenu"><li class="pddng-lft-md pddng-rght-sm"><span id="tone-slider" title="tone"></span></li><li class="pddng-rght-sm"><a href="" class="pddng-lft-0 ps-link dark-grey no-decor del font-85" style="padding-left: 14px;"><i class="icon icon-delete"></i> ' + i18n['ps-deleteArticleToneLabel'] + '</a></li></ul></span>';

      $(tag).appendTo($el);

      var $slider = $('#tone-slider', $el);
      var $delLink = $('a.del', $el);
      var $dropdown = $('span.dropdown', $el);

      $('a.dropdown-toggle', $dropdown).on('click', function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', $dropdown).toggle();
      });

      $slider.kendoSlider({
        change: function(e) {
          var va = valueAccessor();
          va.value(e.value);
          if ($.isFunction(va.handleUserInput)) {
            va.handleUserInput();
          }
        },
        showButtons: false,
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
        smallStep: 1,
        value: valueAccessor().value() || 0,
        tickPlacement: 'none',
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        }
      });


      $('.k-draghandle', $el).off('keydown');


      $delLink.on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        if ($delLink.attr('disabled')) {
          return;
        }

        var va = valueAccessor();
        va.value(null);
        if ($.isFunction(va.handleUserInput)) {
          va.handleUserInput();
        }

      });

      $el.data('slider', $slider.data("kendoSlider"));
      $el.data('deleteButton', $delLink);
      $el.data('dropdown', $dropdown);
    } else {
      $('<span href="" data-tone></span>').appendTo(element);
    }
  },

  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

    var toneValues = {
      '1': {
        name: i18n['ps-tonePositive'],
        val: 1,
        css: 'icon-tone-positive'
      },

      '0': {
        name: i18n['ps-toneNeutral'],
        val: 0,
        css: 'icon-tone-neutral'
      },

      '-1': {
        name: i18n['ps-toneNegative'],
        val: 0,
        css: 'icon-tone-negative'
      },

    };

    var $tone = $('*[data-tone]', element);
    var val = valueAccessor().value() || 0;
    var tone = toneValues[val.toString()] || toneValues['0'];

    $tone.removeClass()
      .addClass('icon').addClass(tone.css)
      .attr('title', tone.name);

    if (valueAccessor().settingToneEnabled) {
      $('#tone-slider', element).data("kendoSlider").value(val);
    }
  },

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove the keydown handler.
See [demo](http://jsbin.com/zukodakale/1/).

Comment: Thanks Tarek. That is what I was doing (see the code in the edited question). However, that is not doing the trick for me. Any ideas?

Comment: could u make a fiddle

Comment: Tarek, here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UncleZen/7b6kdowd/. It works just fine here. But as weird as it sounds, it does not work in my app. Something must be interfering...